# Why do I always have something missing in my understanding of topics which always lead me to solve problems incorrectly?

Tags: education, didactics

I am a computer science masters student, I come from a background of engineering and not CS. My problem is whenever I have a problem set, a programming task or an exam, I always try hard to understand the question and think for the right answers, but I usually either get stuck or have a wrong answer. When I seek help I figure out I wasn’t completely understanding the topic of the question itself, missing some part of the information or even having a wrong understanding to some parts.
So my question is, how can I approach a computer science topic "for e.g. operating systems" and have a good understanding with the right depth, to have a better comprehension and to be able perform better at programming  tasks and exams.

Comment: (Did you try to use a) a spelling checker b) machine translation (especially of problem statements)?)

Comment: @greybeard yes i did, and if i still have any spelling mistakes i would be more than happy if you can point them out or edit them, thanks.

Comment: @greybeard thanks for the edits